# how to setup a breakpoints in DLL of unmanaged code developed in netcobol windows version

Tags: .net, dllimport, netcobol

I am very new to the Web technology. So incase I am not able to mentioned something correctly please pardon me and can ask me again.
I have an application which is developed in NetCobol for .net environment. In this application I am calling a DLL which is for unmanaged code (Netcobol windows version). I am able to set up breakpoint into Managed code (Netcobol for .net) but don't know how to setup breakpoints to unmanaged code DLL (Netcobol for Windows) being called. Since when I am debugging the code getting issue with DLL code. So want to put some breakpoints in DLL unmanaged code. So that I would able to identify the location of the issue coming from.
Can anyone help me in this regards.
Regards
MainframeToWeb

I have .PDB file of unmanaged code and the same placed in bin/debug folder where I kept the DLL file too

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment cause I haven't enough rep to do it, so I put my comment as an answer. Maybe it'll help.

Did you try to step into using debug? If you have a .pdb file of the unmanaged library in the app deployment folder then VS/Rider probably should allow you to debug it using 'step into'

Comment: Hi akushnikov,  Thanks a lot! I have .pdb. file of unmanaged code & kept it in bin/debug folder and source code of the unmanaged code kept in same folder. Now I am not able to understand where to add break point, is it in .pdb file or in the source code of the unmanaged code? definitely not in .pdb file. And if we add breakpoint in source code of the .dll called (Unmanaged source code). Then while debugging, the control is not going to source code of unmanaged code where added breakpoint. Please guide me how to add breakpoint & debug the unmanaged code which is being called from managed code.

Comment: Try this link. The first answer describes how to set up your debug session having both DLL and PDB files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383026/debugging-with-pdb-file-and-source-code-file-in-visual-studio

Comment: I have gone through the link you have provided here. And also have setup the path of my symbol (.pdb) file . Even I am not able to debug the .DLL 32-bit code. Actually the scenario is like this : I have a netCobol .net code which is calling a unmanaged code which is developed at 32-bit netCobol for windows. the DLL file I have kept in the the debug folder and also I have kept the source code in the same folder. If possible can you please connect with me on my email id 'srindianrajput@gmail.com' - I am very much new to this netcobol for .net stuff.    thanks a lot